# How to reduce the degree of sparseness of a 2D numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a very sparse array, for illustration like the following:

```
arr = array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2],
             [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 7, 0, 0, 4, 0]])
```

Since the columns indexed 0 and 3 are all zeros I want to delete them and get the result as this:

```
array([[1, 0, 0, 2],
       [0, 2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [7, 0, 4, 0]])
```

I thought I can check every column by

```
for i in len(arr):
    if arr[:, i] != 0:
        newarr = np.column_stack((newarr, arr[:, i]))
```

But I encounter an error which teaches me to use a.all()..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a simple indexing, by picking the columns that have at least one non-zero item (using `any()` over the first axis):

```
In [9]: arr[:, arr.any(0)]
Out[9]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 2],
       [0, 2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [7, 0, 4, 0]])
```

Comment: Awesome! You're right.. Could you please help explain a bit?